# read somewhat structured text file into array in C++

Tags: c++, python, arrays, input

I would like to reproduce the following python code in C++, but have run into some trouble. The function read_file reads a text file, tests the first word in each line to see if it is an integer. If the first word is an integer (4 or more digits) all of the words on that line are added into a list, z, as floats. In the other case the line is simply added as a string to a list. The list of lists (z) is converted to a 2D numpy array and returned with rest.

```
def read_file(f):
    srchp = re.compile(r'^\d{4,}\s') # beg. of line, digit min 4, white space
    f = open(f)
    rest = [] 
    z = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()] # read file, strip whitespace at beg./end of line,
    #store in z as list of strings. each line is at its own offset
    for i in range(len(z)-1,-1,-1):
        if not srchp.search(z[i]): #if regex does not match
            rest.append(z.pop(i)) #append to list rest
        else:
            z[i] = map(float,z[i].split())
    f.close()
    return numpy.array(z),rest
```

What data types should I use for the containers in C++ (vector of vectors? arrays?)? At the end of the day I want to use the array to do some statistical analysis. I'd be grateful for any help in converting this code to C++.

The following is an excerpt from a file that needs to be read.

```
TEMP_INF                          700.000000                    SCALAR

NAME                              VALUE                        TYPE  DIMENSIONS
TEMP_REF                          25.0000000                    SCALAR

  ***** POST1 ELEMENT TABLE LISTING *****                                      

 STAT        MIXED           MIXED           MIXED           MIXED   
 ELEM        X               Y               Z               TEMP    
23261      0.56292E-03    -0.96401E-02     0.24093          755.91    
23262     -0.16635E-03    -0.97998E-02     0.24080          756.25    
23263     -0.17039E-03    -0.10374E-01     0.24025          757.65    
23264      0.12895E-02    -0.74483E-02     0.24242          751.64    
23265      0.67515E-03    -0.80538E-02     0.24209          752.62    
23266      0.10350E-02    -0.86614E-02     0.24164          753.92    
23267      0.56032E-03    -0.88420E-02     0.24105          756.49    
23268      0.13782E-02    -0.10792E-01     0.23978          758.74
```

Answer (score 1):

Because each row looks like it holds an int and a float, it would be a decent idea to declare a `struct` with that information.

```
struct row {
  int elem;
  float x, y, z, temp;
};
```

Now you can can create a `vector<row>` to hold your information.

```
 vector<row> rows;
```

For each row, you can insert elements like so:

```
row r;
cin >> r.elem >> r.x >> r.y >> r.z >> r.temp;
rows.push_back(r);
```